# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' with hibernate-jpa-2.0-api dependency added

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I've got problem with entityManagerFactory. I've got error :

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'.
```

I've read that I should add to my dependency hibernate-jpa-2.0-api and remove persistance-api if exists. persistance-api didnt exists in my pom.xml, hibernate-jpa-2.0-api was missing. I've added it and I think I've read almost everything about this problem but it still exists. Any ideas?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode()Ljavax/persistence/SharedCacheMode;
```

AppContext:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.rd.j2ee.api" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="pl.rd.j2ee.api.dao" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="db.url" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="pl.rd.j2ee" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Angular</groupId>
<artifactId>Angular</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Angular</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<description>Angular</description>

<properties>
    <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
    <spring.framework.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <dependency.aspectj.version>1.6.10</dependency.aspectj.version>
    <dependency.version.jbehave>3.6.2</dependency.version.jbehave>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Tests -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kubek2k</groupId>
        <artifactId>springockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kubek2k</groupId>
        <artifactId>springockito-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.catch-exception</groupId>
        <artifactId>catch-exception</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Data Access -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Others -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${dependency.aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${dependency.aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>17.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine which Maven dependencies are causing the problem, do the following:

1. Clear or backup your Maven repository, for example: mv ~/.m2/repository ~/.m2/repository-backup
2. Build you project.
3. Use any tool which is able to search through jars in your repo to scan all dependencies for mentioned class (for example zzfind or use unzip -l in loop).
4. By excluding each dependency from your project you will be able to find one which is introducing the problem.

Comment: hibernate-entitymanager includes hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.So I removed hibernate-jpa-2.0-api dependency and tried to start app, but it didn't work. Next thing I tried was added exclusion to hibernate-entitymanager but unfortunately it didn't work too...

Answer (score 0):

quote from another resource:

> I got around this problem by replacing
>   com.springsource.javax.persistence-1.0.0.jar with
>   hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar.
>
> If you have both jars in your classpath, simply remove
>   com.springsource.javax.persistence-1.0.0.jar in other to rule out
>   conflicts.

- delete javax.persistence from pom.xml

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/80160-issues-with-interface-persistenceunitinfo-in-com-springsource-javax-persistence-1-0-0